# Getting Info Migration from google+ to google signin

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client, google-signin

As per google developer page `The Google+ Sign-in feature is fully deprecated and is being shut down on March 7, 2019. This will be a progressive shutdown, with intermittent failures starting as early as January 28, 2019.
Developers should migrate to the more comprehensive Google Sign-in authentication system.`

I’m trying to migrate from google+ sign-in api to new google signin api. I need to get the user info. Whats the replacement for `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me`?